# @font-face in iOS for Persian fonts

Tags: ios, css, fonts

I'm trying to embed a Persian font (BYekan) on my responsive website, and currently using the code below I've been able to achieve my goal in Chrome and Desktop Safari:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'BYekan';
src: url('/font/BYekan.eot');
src: url('/font/BYekan.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('/font/BYekan.woff') format('woff'),
url('/font/BYekan.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('/font/BYekan.svg#BYekan') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

However, it doesn't work in iOS Safari except for numbers. I've already tried [BBC Persian website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/persian/)'s font (BBCNasim) with no luck. Any suggestions?

**Edited:**
[This is](http://hosting.ehsanabbasi.com) the the website that I'm working on. And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fksf9wj8e2kbq41/cjIyGZiZTx) I uploaded the font that I'm using (I downloaded them from a Persian site, and don't know how they've created the different formats of the font. Maybe they used [onlinefontconverter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/) cause it's recommended in their website). If you check my site on Desktop and iPhone, will see the difference.

Comment: You should post a sufficient piece of HTML and CSS and clearly specify the font you are using (where you got it from, not just a name) and how you produced the different font files. Including a URL of an online demo of the problem would be a useful addition to this.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've added the link to the site and the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Your @font-face rule looks fine.

I think you might be encountering a lack of support for characters.

Try setting the unicode range for your font to all possible unicode characters.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'BYekan';
    src: url('/font/BYekan.eot');
    src: url('/font/BYekan.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/font/BYekan.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/font/BYekan.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/font/BYekan.svg#BYekan') format('svg');
         font-weight: normal;
         font-style: normal;
         unicode-range: U+00-FFFF;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Like I said, I've tried BBC Persian font which is fine in iOS. But I couldn't get it work on my site with the same code.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. I thought that would be it. Hmm strange... Perhaps see what font Google translate uses? I don't know if they translate into Farsi though... The BBC font might not work due to licensing issues.

Comment: That's fine. Yeah, it's strange. I checked many Persian websites with the custom fonts which is working fine. But they have the same issue in iOS! Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your font file is problematic and is not designed for Web.
Refer to this link for full description and web-friendly version download: http://www.wedesign.ir/css/css3-font-face-methods-and-optimized-font-firefox6